# Generating data for a graph

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3Cau-qmSwk
Note: Yes I know it's possible with VBS. But I'm convinced it can be done using some more or less standard Excel features. I simply want to learn more of those features by solving this problem and this is what that bounty is about.

Example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s4IvVe-jiHmvlij8Zv0HWLYFzsCV_4nz/view?usp=sharing

Short explanation:
On the second Sheet ( Named Graph ) is what I want to achieve.
Prices for hosts A, B and C are generated by changing number of files on the first Sheet ( Named Prices )

Longer:
I have a graph that compares prices from a few different hosting providers.

Each one calculates it's price based on a few different factors.

For example one charges for views other charges for GB storage other for Transfer. I've brought them to a common denominator "a file number" so when I change a value in a "file" cell all of the prices change accordingly for each hosting provider.

I would like to present that on a graph.
That would give me a better understanding how each one of those hosting providers would scare overtime.

Do I have to input into the file cell 50,100,200,400 copying those prices each time onto the other sheet of is there a better, easier or maybe even more dynamic way to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share an example for how it's set-up and the desired output?

Comment: @Isolated: Ok. I've edited first post and added an example.

Comment: I don't so how your graph is going to be non-linear vs. number of files, so the example included is misleading.

Comment: I've added a video explaining what I am looking for. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: I think i solve your problem but got deleted No reason Asked just got deleted

Comment: @WIL That's unfortunate man. I haven't done this. Could repost your answer. I would really like to part ways with those 50 points but there isn't anyone that has given me an answer.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: well you found your answer anyway. but heres what I suggested to split your data into columns. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s4IvVe-jiHmvlij8Zv0HWLYFzsCV_4nz/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the following formula:

`=(Prices!B$2*$A2*Prices!$B$8)+(Prices!B$3*Prices!$B$7*Prices!$B$8)+(Prices!B$4*Prices!$B$7*$A2)`

In your "Graph" sheet, cell B2, where you have the table laying out the values, simply drag it down and across to fill out the other prices and hosts. Changing the file size in column A will update the formulae and thus the value and the graph.

Comment: Yes, this formula would work well. I would also suggest to use this formula in a table which the graph will be based up on. If the graph is "linked" to a table, OP doesn't need to add or remove manually new values in the graph. Everything will be automatically :)

Comment: Holly crap it does work. I just tried it incorrectly. Could you explain it to me a bit?

Comment: Oh ok nevermind. I've split it into multiple lines and it became clear. :) ~Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help!  Wizhi's suggestion is a good one as well, if you put that range into a table by pressing CTRL + T the graph will automatically add any new vendors or rows you add to the table.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the price is calculated as follows

```
price = 
    (price per view) * (num of views) +
    (price per transfer) * (num of views) * (file size) +
    (price per storage) * (num of files) * (file size)
```

So, just add the appropriate relations in excel for the above price model based on the values you want to track.